# Minimising an embedded swift framework size

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to figure out how to make my embedded swift framework as small as possible in a host app that is using it.
My framework is compiling to a 12MB universal .framework file (**release mode**) that can be used in both simulator and device builds. After I embed it to an app, the app itself is gaining about ±3.4MB of size (post-compile), 3.4MB is pretty big and I think it can be minimised. 
I tried to play with most of the compilation options. 
In build settings I disabled the generating of debug symbols and I also checked that in release they are stripped out. 
[strip symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9EJR.png) &
[generate debug symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrFNX.png)

How can I make sure that when my swift framework is embedded to an app it will add as ״little״ as possible to the app overall size ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running lipo -info on the binary file inside the framework. If it specifies unnecessary architectures you can remove those, also with lipo:

```
lipo MyFramework.framework/MyFramework -remove i386 -output MyFramework
```